# Get rid of trending searches in Apple Music (iOS)

Tags: ios, apple-music

Is there any hidden preference or other technique that could make "trending" searches to not be displayed in Apple Music in iOS? I couldn't care less what others are interested in.

I certainly don't see any possibility in settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't let you change things like that.

It's common now to engage users when they're searching for something (think Twitter, Instagram, Facebook) and it's really not that invasive compared to the other platforms.

While they aren't competing for ad dollars, more engagement means you're more likely to resubscribe as you get deeper into the product.

Comment: Not in the GUI, but quite commonly with preferences in files. Which is what I was hoping for.

Comment: "Preferences in files"?

Comment: Editing preference files directly. This is an easy and not uncommon way to reach preferences in macOS that aren't in the GUI. Unfortunately Apple seem to have changed this with iOS 8.3 and later.

Comment: i e, Apple prevents access to the places where preference files resides.

Comment: I've since complained to Apple about this. In my experience I'm seldom alone about getting irritated about stupid details and sometimes Apple changes what the complaint concerns, for one reason or another.